# Magento 2 : How to change default date format every where in magento?

Tags: magento2, date, dateformat

I want to change the default **date format** like `mm/dd/yy to dd/mm/yy` for `en_us locale` in admin as well as front-end.

**Don't want to change the locale for that.**

Comment: Every where means ? What you want exactly ?

Comment: You want all product details page ?

Comment: Every where means each and every place where we show and take input by default Magento format, like order, invoice etc....

Comment: I don't know it's working perfect or not.

But you try in `Stores/Configuration/General/Locale Options, set Locale` and then you go in `Stores/Configuration/Catalog/Date & Time Custom Options` and set your format @AshishJagnani.

Comment: If we change the locale from en_us to en_uk then it will work, other wise not. The other date setting is not working and I don't want to change the locale setting.

Comment: is there a way to change the display format of the date from a general setting, so that it displays the date format which we selected, this includes order grid; order email, etc,.. did you find any answer @AshishJagnani?

Answer (score 4):

To change visible date format in date inputs You need to set proper Interface Locale in the Account Setting.

[image: Account Setting > Interface Locale]

After that You will see changes on the Edit Product Page.

[image: Edit Product Page - date range in proper format]

To change dates in frontend catalog go to:
**Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog** 
and find 
**Date & Time Custom Options**

There you can configure date format on store front catalog.

Comment: Changing the locale (at least to de_DE doesn't change the date format on order grid)